# How to get Text in <span> contain <a>

Tags: javascript, cypress

I try to get text of `<span>` in below HTML:

```
<td data-v-c0a5153a="" style="min-width: 300px; width: 300px;">
<span><!---->
    <span class="v-tooltip v-tooltip--bottom"></span>
    <span aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <a class="downloaded--text">Apple</a>
        <!---->
    </span>
</span>
<span>
    <span>,</span>
    <span class="v-tooltip v-tooltip--bottom">
        <!---->
    </span>
    <span aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <a class="downloaded--text">Water mellon</a>
        <!---->
    </span>
</span>
<!---->
```

Here is my code:

```
cy.get('#freeg-list-table-report')
            .find('tbody tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(5)
            .find('span').invoke('text')
            .then(text => {  
                cy.log(text)
            })
```

Log display:

> *Apple Apple*
>
> *Water mellon Water mellon*

Why is it duplicated? What should I do to get:

> *Apple*
>
> *Water mellon*

---- Update ----

I got an array from

listA = ["Apple", "Water mellon"]

Here my code:

```
    const listA = []
    cy.get('#freeg-list-table-report')
        .find('tbody tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(5)
        .find('span')
        .find('a')
        .each(a => {
            const text = a.text()
            listA.push(text)
            cy.log(text);
        })
    cy.log(listA)
    cy.log(listA[0])
```

But the issue occurs when I try cy.log(listA[0]) => result: **null**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because you have two layered `<span>` and each one contributes the `innerText` it sees.

By way of debugging, if you run this

```js
cy.get('span')
  .then($els => {
    const debug = [...$els].map((el, index) => {
      return `${el.tagName} #${index}: ${el.innerText}`
    })
    console.log(debug)
  })
```

you see the result is

```js
[
  'SPAN #0: Apple ', 
  'SPAN #1: ', 
  'SPAN #2: Apple ', 
  'SPAN #3: , Water mellon', 
  'SPAN #4: ,', 
  'SPAN #5: ', 
  'SPAN #6: Water mellon'
]
```

That's because `invoke('text')` returns the `text` from the current element and ***all descendent elements***.

So the `SPAN #0` gives you `Apple` even though it's not directly having that text, because it's child `<span>` has it.

---

If you change the element to `<a>` you get the correct result

```js
cy.get('#freeg-list-table-report')
  .find('tbody tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(5)
  .find('a').invoke('text')
  .then(text => {  
     cy.log(text)           // log: Apple Water mellon
  })
```

---

If you must use `.find('span')` for some reason, the `.invoke('text')` needs to be changed

```js
cy.get('#freeg-list-table-report')
  .find('tbody tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(5)
  .find('span')
  .then($els => $els.clone().children().remove().end().text() ) // self explanatory 
  .then(text => {  
     cy.log(text)           // log: Apple Water mellon
  })
```

Comment: I got list[] contain array to compare with data.json. But when I log( list) it display correct array, I log (list[0]) result is undefined. See my update.

Comment: A bonus question! That one is because `cy.log(listA)` is grabbing the `listA` value at the start of the test, before `.each(...)` has run. Easy to fix, just use `.each(...).then(() => cy.log(listA))` and it will wait for the values you appended.

Answer (score -1):

This Cypress code logs the text of the  tags in the format you requested:

```
cy.get('span a.downloaded--text').each(($el) => {
  const text = $el.text().trim()
  cy.log(text)
})
```

`cy.get()` selects all the  elements with the class `downloaded--text` inside `<span>` tags. Then the `.each()` method iterates over each element, and `.text()` get the text content.

Inside the `.each()` function, we format the text by trimming any extra whitespace, and then log it using the `cy.log()` command. This will output the text to the Cypress test runner console in the format you requested.

Also, I used the `.each()` method instead of `.invoke('text')` so I could log the text separately for each element, rather than combining them in a single string.

Comment: But **why is it duplicated**?